# how to allocate a struct outside the main()?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have built a book struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct _book{
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char authors[AUTHORS_NAME_LENGTH];
    char publisher[PUBLISHER_NAME_LENGTH];
    char genre[GENRE_LENGTH];
    int year;
    int num_pages;
    int copies;
}book;
```

i'm trying to define a library which is an array of books, so that later on i could deposit books in the library with another function.
had problems with memory write/read when defined the library like this `library[BOOK_NUM]`, so i decided to allocate.

the thing is, it only lets my allocate inside the main function.
when i write this line:

```
book *library = (book*)malloc(BOOK_NUM*sizeof(book));
```

outside the `main()` it gives me an error:

> IntelliSense: function call is not allowed in a constant expression
>
> error C2099: initializer is not a constant

but if i move the above line to be inside `main()` it works. why is that?

also, what is the better way to define the array so that i could change it later with other functions?

Comment: *Where* do you write that declaration? As a global variable? In a function? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: You just need to put it inside a function.  It's a dynamic initialization.

Comment: Oh, and [in C you should not cast the return of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (or any other function returning `void *`).

Comment: Create an module/ADT called library and put the allocation there.

Comment: No matter what you do, it will be painful and error-prone. Use C++ and its containers, or better C#. It frees you of most memory management problems and lets you focus on the actual stuff you want to get done.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: I guess it is a homework about programming in C. I would recommend Ocaml instead of C#

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Interesting. Well, C++ and C# are superficially similar enough to C to make the transition (perhaps deceivingly) easy. Btw, seeing that you are French, are you involved in OCaml? (Which I have no knowledge of so far.)

Comment: I worked one year at INRIA inside the Ocaml team (in 2004)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might declare a global or static variable, assuming `BOOK_NUM` is some `#define`-d *constant* (e.g. `#define BOOK_NUM 100` somewhere before in your code):

```
 book library[BOOK_NUM];
```

However, heap allocation is generally preferable, because the resource usage is limited at runtime, not at compile-time or start of execution time.

If `BOOK_NUM` was extremely big (eg a billion) you could have an issue (program won't be runnable because of lack of memory).

If `BOOK_NUM` was slightly small (e.g. a dozen) you could have an issue in running some cases (not enough space for books).

If you (wrongly!) declared `book library[BOOK_NUM];` as some *local* variable (e.g. in `main`), the call frame should be small enough (because the entire [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is limited to a few mega-bytes, so individual call frames should not exceed a few kilobytes) so `BOOK_NUM` should be kept small (a few dozens at most).

To quote the [GNU coding standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Semantics):

> **4.2 Writing Robust Programs**
>
> Avoid arbitrary limits on the length or number of any data structure, including file names, lines, files, and symbols, by allocating all data structures dynamically

So a better way could be to have:

```
typedef struct book_st {
  char* name;
  char* authors;
  char* publisher;
  char* genre;
  int year;
  int num_pages;
  int copies;
} book;
```

then a "making function" (or "constructing" function) like

```
/* returns a freshly allocated book to be deleted by delete_book;
   the strings arguments should be not null and are duplicated. */
book* make_book(const char*n, const char*a, const char*p, 
                const char*g, int y, int np, int c) {
  assert (n != NULL);
  assert (a != NULL);
  assert (p != NULL);
  assert (g != NULL);
  book* b = malloc(sizeof(book));
  if (!b) { perror("malloc book"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  memset (b, 0, sizeof(book)); // useless, but safe
  char* pname = strdup(n);
  if (!pname) { perror("strdup name"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  char* pauth = strdup(a);
  if (!pauth) { perror("strdup author"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  char *ppub = strdup(p);
  if (!ppub) { perror("strdup publisher"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  char *pgenre = strdup(g);
  if (!pgenre) { perror("strdup genre"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  b->name = pname;
  b->authors = pauth;
  b->publishers = ppub;
  b->genre = pgenre;
  b->year = y;
  b->num_pages = np;
  b->copies = c;
  return b;
}
```

Notice that *every* call to `malloc` should be tested, because `malloc` could fail. Here I just exit with some error message; in some cases you would want to recover from `malloc` failure (e.g. a server might want to continue processing *future* requests), but that is boringly difficult (you might need to `free` any unseless `malloc`-ed pointer so far, etc...).

Of course, you need a destroying or deleting function to release memory, like:

```
/* destroy and free a book obtained by make_book */
void delete_book(book*b) {
  if (!b) return;
  free (b->name), b->name = NULL;
  free (b->authors), b->authors = NULL;
  free (b->publisher), b->publisher = NULL;
  free (b->genre), b->genre = NULL;
  free (b);
}
```

Notice my [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) style. I am clearing the `malloc`-ed `book` pointer before filling it; I am setting to `NULL` every pointer field in `book` just after `free`-ing it. In principle both are useless.

BTW, you could make your library a `struct` ending with a [flexible array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) member:

```
struct library_st {
   unsigned size; // allocate size
   unsigned nbbooks; // actual number of books
   book* books[]; // actually, size slots
};
```

and have functions like `struct library_st*make_library(unsigned s);` and `struct library_st*add_book(struct library_st*lib, book*book);` which would return perhaps an updated and reallocated library.

The main thing in C is to document the memory allocation discipline. *Every function* should say (at least in a comment) who is in charge of freeing pointers and how.

Read much more (at least for concepts and terminology) about [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak#Reference_counting_and_cyclic_references), [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). Notice that [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) is [not a silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet).

Consider using Linux as your primary development environment on your laptop. It has good tools (`gcc -Wall -g -fsanitize=address` with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), `gdb`, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), [Boehm's conservative GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) ...) and lots of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) whose source code is worth studying to learn more about C programming.

BTW, to store your library on the disk, consider [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) techniques (and textual formats à la [JSON](http://json.org/)), or perhaps [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or some real database (PostGreSQL, MongoDB, ...)

Comment: #define BOOK_NUM 50. 

i did encounter problems when tried to define like this :
    book library[BOOK_NUM];

thats why i tried to allocate. but had also problems with allocation when the malloc was outside of main()

Comment: when i defined book library[BOOK_NUM];         it gave me some problems with other functions when i tried to put values in the array

Comment: rtucan, defining a global array of books is just fine (it may even be a reasonable design decision). It should just work. Which "problems with other functions" did you encounter?

Answer (score 2):

You can only call malloc inside a function. main () is a function. You can write other functions. You can't just declare a global variable and initialise it by calling a function.